# Is there any way to expire documents from the database?

Tags: cloudant

I have a request from customer to clean app all documents from a particular view on cloudant that are more than 30 days old. I did some search on cloudant documentations but cannot find any such feature to set expiration date for documents. Search online yielded one very similar query but with no answer. Does anyone know what would be the best way to achieve this ? Please let me know.
It would be far simpler set something like a daily scheduler for the clean up than look at writing a new program for it.

Comment: I found something that looks promising. I am seeing if a combination of a script and curl can do that job. Need to do a simple test.
https://cloudant.com/accessing-the-api-using-curl-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that the current date is `2015-11-10T17:44:31+00:00` (in ISO 8601 format). You have a document with a timestamp of `2015-10-10T17:44:31.000Z`:

```
{
  "_id": "791bb0b8ff1d8f2be5dd15893ca4a85f",
  "_rev": "1-b1007c119c53fccb69fae396028d16e1",
  "timestamp": "2015-10-10T17:44:31.000Z"
}
```

And another document with a timestamp of `2015-10-12T17:44:31.000Z`:

```
{
  "_id": "791bb0b8ff1d8f2be5dd15893cbe6e2b",
  "_rev": "1-d068d8b63ca848406082f31e4b20e927",
  "timestamp": "2015-10-12T17:44:31.000Z"
}
```

You want to query for documents that are not more than 30 days old, which would include the second document but not the first. Create an index on the `timestamp` field (in your application you would probably add additional fields to the index so that you can add these fields to your query):

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      "timestamp"
    ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

Compute the ISO 8601 timestamp for 30 days ago. In JavaScript:

```
var currentTime = new Date("2015-11-10T17:44:31+00:00");
var thirtyDaysAgo = new Date(currentTime.getTime() - (30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
console.log(thirtyDaysAgo.toISOString());
```

This should provide you with the timestamp of `2015-10-11T17:44:31.000Z`. Let's then query for documents that have a timestamp greater than or equal to this time:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "timestamp": {
      "$gte": "2015-10-11T17:44:31.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

This query only returns the newer document with the timestamp of `2015-10-12T17:44:31.000Z`. As I mentioned previously, you would probably also want to add additional fields to the index and then query against these fields as well.

Comment: Thanks you ! I am looking into this and will let you know soon.